# Copy Three Columns from one workbook into another when all three ranges are different than the original ranges using Command Button

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I am attempting to copy three ranges, Column A, B and C in Workbook 1 to columns B, C, and G in Workbook 2 using a command button and without having to have the destination workbook open. Here, Column A from WB1 goes to column B WB2, Column B from WB1 goes to column C WB2, and Column C from WB1 goes to column G WB2.

I've been able to copy and paste A and B into B and C using the following Code, but cannot figure out how to get C into G without using a different Command Button.
I need the button to completely update the columns in the destination worksheet when it is clicked.
This is how I went about the first two columns :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2:B250").Copy
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\og677\Desktop\N
\Matlab\VehicleList1.xlsx"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub
```

I thought I might need to set the ranges so I was trying something like this, but I didn't know how and was getting in error where I attempt to set wb2.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim O As Workbook
    
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    
    Dim ESN As Worksheet
    Dim List As Worksheet
    
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    
    
    Set O = ThisWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("C:\Users.xlsx")
    
    Set ESN = O.Sheets("ESN Regression")
    Set List = VehicleList.Sheets("Sheet1")
     
    
    n = 2
    
    For I = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(O.Columns.EntireColumn(1))
    
       
        If Cells(I, "I").Value = "Yes" Then
    
            List.Cells(n, "B").Value = ESN.Cells(I, "A")
            List.Cells(n, "C").Value = ESN.Cells(I, "B")
            List.Cells(n, "G").Value = ESN.Cells(I, "C")
            
           
            n = n + 1
    
        End If
    
    Next
    
End Sub
```

I'd like to be able to keep my first attempt if it could be done but I'm open to any changes at all.

Comment: `Workbooks()` indexes off of just the name, not the full path - use `Set wb2 = Workbooks("VehicleList1")` if it's already open, otherwise `Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\og677\Desktop\NightHawk\Matlab\VehicleList1.xlsx")`. Everything else looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:B250").Copy
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\og677\Desktop\N\Matlab\VehicleList.xlsx"
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

ThisWorkbook.Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C250").Copy
Windows("VehicleList.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 7).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the range where you want to paste. 
This is how I did in my macro to copy from wbTarget column A to wbThis column B

```
wbTarget.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A14:A100").Copy
wbThis.Activate
wbThis.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B14:B100").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Split the copy/paste in more steps called by the same Command, so that A and B are pasted to A and B, while C is pasted to G

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Workbooks.Open Filename:="enter file name.xlsx"
'Column A
Windows("Workbook1.xlsm").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Workbook2.xlsx").Activate
Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
'Column B
Windows("Workbook1.xlsm").Activate
Range("B1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Workbook2.xlsx").Activate
Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
'Column C
Windows("Workbook1.xlsm").Activate
Range("C1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Workbook2.xlsx").Activate
Range("G1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I received an error referring to the code where the range is selected before being pasted.

 `Windows("Workbook2.xlsx").Activate

Range("B1").Select  ' Error occurred here

ActiveSheet.Paste`

Any ideas why? It looks fine to me
@sn152
Thanks for the help